# Client can connect to my openvpn but cannot reach internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, centos, openvpn

I have the following server.conf:

```
# listen on? (optional)
local 192.168.1.102

# port
port 443

# TCP
proto tcp

#tunnel
dev tun

# Certs
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh2048.pem

# Configure server mode
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2


# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Push routes to the client
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.1.102 255.255.255.0"

# Redirect
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# DNS
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

# Use same key mult clients
duplicate-cn

# The keepalive
keepalive 10 120

# Compression
comp-lzo

# presistence options
persist-key
persist-tun

# log
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

The server's network card is `eno1`. 
The server is at `192.168.1.102` in my router's network (the client is also originally in that netowork too). My router has the prort forwarding rule:

```
Source net:
source port: 443
Dest ip: 192.168.1.102
Dest port: 443
```

The iptables rule I made (on the openvpn server):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
```

And I have the following client config for openvpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp

#Server IP and Port
remote 192.168.1.102 443

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
```

I am able to connect to the VPN and it correctly gives me an ip of `10.8.0.6`.

But when i try to go to anything on the internet, it just times out. How do i make the openvpn pass through the request?

*NOTE: When I look in the openvpn log, the last thing I see from the client is "SENT CONTROL". Nothing about trying to get to the web address I'm attempting to reach.*

(I also turned off the firewall and disabled selinux)

Answer (score 2):

Change the *iptables* rule to:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

and make sure you have IPv4 enabled,

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and that you have no *iptables* rules blocking the *FORWARD* chain of the *filter* table.